# пропали среды разработки phpstorm clion intelliJ idea на ubuntu 14.04 lts

Tags: ubuntu, phpstorm, clion

исчезли среды разработки на ubuntu и при переустановки он работает только при помощи терминала и как только закрываю терминал и среда разработки исчезает что делать?

Comment: какого терминала ?

Comment: что именно работает только при помощи терминала - ubuntu или idea,etc.? о каком терминале идет речь? и что значит "среда разработки исчезает"?

Comment: Может, имеется в виду, что они теперь не запускаются через desktop entry? И Вы можете запустить их только из терминала? Попробуйте пересоздать desktop entries с помощью Tools | Create Desktop Entry

Comment: а то, что приложение, запущенное из терминала, закрывается при его закрытии - нормальное поведение

Comment: я пробовал этот вариант но при закрытия он так же исчезает

Comment: я переустанавливаю программу на терминале ubuntu и при запуске пробовал создать desktop entry и закрываю терминал и снова исчезает с панели

Comment: http://www.linuxrussia.com/2013/09/shortcut-ubuntu-sh.html